# Thunderbird Lightning Calendar sync or import from MS Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook, sync, thunderbird, calendar, lightning

I have recently started using Thunderbird as my mail client and I like it (much better than what they want me to use - Outlook). Although I am well settled with email and contacts, I still want to import or sync my calendar. I have not come across any decent solution for that.

Please help.

Comment: No answer? No one? I feel like an outcast...:(

Comment: Importing is easy.  I'm not aware of any way to synch.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I share my Outlook 2007 calendar with Thunderbird?](http://superuser.com/questions/248795/how-can-i-share-my-outlook-2007-calendar-with-thunderbird) (newer question but better canonical reference, with accepted answer)

Answer (score 1):

You don't really.  I'm the sole Linux user out of 1200 employees, I do all my at-work mail in Thunderbird on my Mint desktop, with the Lightning extension.  When I get Calendar stuff, I add it in Ligthning but don't reply to the invite, then pop into the Office 365 mail there and accept it (which blocks my calendar).

I do few enough meetings/appointments that the lack of true synching doesn't bother me much...

Answer (score -1):

In Outlook...EXPORT calendar in comma delineated form.
Resulting file will likely end up in your MY DOCUMENTS FILE.

In Thunderbird select IMPORT FILE and use the .csv format...then select the CALENDER file from MY DOCUMENTS.

Should do the trick.

Comment: It did not. I want to sync the calendars.