# How can I share my Outlook 2007 calendar with Thunderbird?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, thunderbird, email-client

just wondering if there is a way how to share calendars between Outlook 2007 & Thunderbird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an option in outlook to export calendars to ical or vcalendar formats. I think there would be options to import these formats in thunderbird also.

update: you will have to install an add-on 'lightning' in order to use this . guide here : http://www.ehow.com/how_7201355_import-outlook-calendar-using-thunderbird.html

Comment: I also don't know. I sent an invitation to one of our developer and they are using Thunderbird and they can't view my calendar I'm using Outlook 2007.

Comment: I tried searching in google but couldn't find the right answer. Most of the answers were crap, sorry. But thanks for this link

Comment: Old thread, but your edit bumped it.  Just to add for future readers: the export/import described here is only needed to dump a whole existing calendar into Thunderbird/Lightning.  Invitations for new, individual events are compatible in both directions.  Outlook on one computer, Thunderbird on another (not on the same network server): you won't get the kind of tight integration as two Outlooks on the same server.